# How to change custom view from external library?

Tags: android, kotlin, view

I am using `payu library`
https://developers.payu.com/en/overview.html

I would like to change some views, as far as I know I only can do it programatically.

So far this is my code:

```
        val linearLayout = (this as ViewGroup).getChildAt(0) as ViewGroup
        val blikContainer = linearLayout.children
            .filterIsInstance<BlikPaymentMethodWidgetExtension>()
            .firstOrNull()
            ?.let {
                getChildAt(0) as ViewGroup
            } ?: throw Exception()

        val blikLinearLayout = blikContainer.getChildAt(1) as ViewGroup
        val textInputLayout = ((blikLinearLayout.getChildAt(0) as ViewGroup).getChildAt(1) as ViewGroup).getChildAt(0) as TextInputLayout

        textInputLayout.removeAllViews()
        val newView = LayoutInflater.from(this.context).inflate(R.layout.payu_blik_content, null)
        textInputLayout.addView(newView, 0)
   
// normally I return here: return textInputLayout.editText
```

but when adding these lines:

```
        val newView = LayoutInflater.from(this.context).inflate(R.layout.payu_blik_content, null)
        textInputLayout.addView(newView, 0)
```

I get error with crash:

```
Exception while processing periodic Task TaskWrapper{task=class t6.g, processed=false}
                                                                                                    java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: t6.g.<init> [class android.content.Context, class p6.a]
                                                                                                        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2363)
```

How to fix this problem, maybe is there better solution?

Comment: Post the entire stack trace

Comment: Also-  what are you trying to do by removing all views from a TextInputLayout and then adding new views to it?  There is literally no reason to ever do that-  if you don't want the text input as is, then you shouldn't be using it to begin with.

Comment: I would like to change this view to another, there is no function like updateView so from my perspective I need to remove it programatically and add another one. Briefly, I would like to change view from the library to my custom written in .xml. I will add stacktrace in 1h. Yes, but how I understand it. These views are connected with inner logic of the library, so I just cannot easily remove it and add my custom one.